# How do I load `config_setting()` into my `.bzl` file?

Tags: bazel

My motivation: our codebase is scattered across over at least 20 git repos. I want to consolidate everything into a single git repo with a single build system. Currently we use SBT, but we think the build would take too long, so I am examining the possibility of using Bazel instead.

Most of our codebase uses Scala 2.12, some of our codebase uses Scala 2.11, and the rest needs to build under both Scala 2.11 and Scala 2.12.

I'm trying to use [bazelbuild/rules_scala](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala).

With the following call to `scala_repositories` in my `WORKSPACE`, I can build using Scala 2.12:

```
scala_repositories(("2.12.6", {
    "scala_compiler": "3023b07cc02f2b0217b2c04f8e636b396130b3a8544a8dfad498a19c3e57a863",
    "scala_library": "f81d7144f0ce1b8123335b72ba39003c4be2870767aca15dd0888ba3dab65e98",
    "scala_reflect": "ffa70d522fc9f9deec14358aa674e6dd75c9dfa39d4668ef15bb52f002ce99fa"
}))
```

If I have the following call instead, I can build using Scala 2.11:

```
scala_repositories(("2.11.12", {
    "scala_compiler": "3e892546b72ab547cb77de4d840bcfd05c853e73390fed7370a8f19acb0735a0",
    "scala_library": "0b3d6fd42958ee98715ba2ec5fe221f4ca1e694d7c981b0ae0cd68e97baf6dce",
    "scala_reflect": "6ba385b450a6311a15c918cf8688b9af9327c6104f0ecbd35933cfcd3095fe04"
}))
```

However, it is not possible to specify in my `BUILD` files on a package level which version(s) of Scala to build with. I must specify this globally in my `WORKSPACE`.

To workaround this, my plan is to set up [configurable attributes](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/common-definitions.html#configurable-attributes), so I can specify `--define scala=2.11` to build with Scala 2.11, and specify `--define scala=2.12` to build with Scala 2.12.

First I tried by putting this code in my `WORKSPACE`:

```
config_setting(
    name = "scala-2.11",
    define_values = {
        "scala": "2.11"
    }
)

config_setting(
    name = "scala-2.12",
    define_values = {
        "scala": "2.12"
    }
)

scala_repositories(
    select(
        {
            "scala-2.11": "2.11.12",
            "scala-2.12": "2.12.6"
        }
    ),
    select(
        {
            "scala-2.11": {
                "scala_compiler": "3e892546b72ab547cb77de4d840bcfd05c853e73390fed7370a8f19acb0735a0",
                "scala_library": "0b3d6fd42958ee98715ba2ec5fe221f4ca1e694d7c981b0ae0cd68e97baf6dce",
                "scala_reflect": "6ba385b450a6311a15c918cf8688b9af9327c6104f0ecbd35933cfcd3095fe04",
            },
            "scala-2.12": {
                "scala_compiler": "3023b07cc02f2b0217b2c04f8e636b396130b3a8544a8dfad498a19c3e57a863",
                "scala_library": "f81d7144f0ce1b8123335b72ba39003c4be2870767aca15dd0888ba3dab65e98",
                "scala_reflect": "ffa70d522fc9f9deec14358aa674e6dd75c9dfa39d4668ef15bb52f002ce99fa"
            }
        }
    )
)
```

But this gave me the error `config_setting cannot be in the WORKSPACE file`.

So then I tried moving code into a Starlark file.

In `tools/build_rules/scala.bzl`:

```
config_setting(
    name = "scala-2.11",
    define_values = {
        "scala": "2.11"
    }
)

config_setting(
    name = "scala-2.12",
    define_values = {
        "scala": "2.12"
    }
)

def scala_version():
    return select(
        {
            "scala-2.11": "2.11.12",
            "scala-2.12": "2.12.6"
        }
    )

def scala_machinery():
    return select(
        {
        "scala-2.11": {
            "scala_compiler": "3e892546b72ab547cb77de4d840bcfd05c853e73390fed7370a8f19acb0735a0",
            "scala_library": "0b3d6fd42958ee98715ba2ec5fe221f4ca1e694d7c981b0ae0cd68e97baf6dce",
            "scala_reflect": "6ba385b450a6311a15c918cf8688b9af9327c6104f0ecbd35933cfcd3095fe04",
        },
        "scala-2.12": {
            "scala_compiler": "3023b07cc02f2b0217b2c04f8e636b396130b3a8544a8dfad498a19c3e57a863",
            "scala_library": "f81d7144f0ce1b8123335b72ba39003c4be2870767aca15dd0888ba3dab65e98",
            "scala_reflect": "ffa70d522fc9f9deec14358aa674e6dd75c9dfa39d4668ef15bb52f002ce99fa"
            }
        }
    )
```

And back in my `WORKSPACE`:

```
load("//tools/build_rules:scala.bzl", "scala_version", "scala_machinery")
scala_repositories(scala_version(), scala_machinery())
```

But now I get this error:

```
tools/build_rules/scala.bzl:1:1: name 'config_setting' is not defined
```

This confuses me, because I thought `config_setting()` was built in. I can't find where I should load it in from.

So, my questions:

- How do I load `config_setting()` into my `.bzl` file?
- Or, is there a better way of controlling from the command line which arguments get passed to `scala_repositories()`?
- Or, is this just not possible?

```
$ bazel version
Build label: 0.17.2-homebrew
Build target: bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Fri Sep 28 10:42:37 2018 (1538131357)
Build timestamp: 1538131357
Build timestamp as int: 1538131357
```

Comment: I am now looking into using [rules_scala_annex](https://github.com/andyscott/rules_scala_annex) instead of rules_scala.

Comment: Just curious, does scala_annex help? It seems what scala annex does iis what I was suggesting https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala/issues/393#issuecomment-419317205

Comment: I'm still getting to grips with rules_scala_annex (and Bazel in general) but yes, it lets me use Scala 2.11 and Scala 2.12 in the same workspace :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you call native code from a bzl file, you must use the `native.` prefix, so in this case you would call `native.config_setting`.

However, this is going to lead to the same error: `config_setting` is a BUILD rule, not a WORKSPACE rule.

If you want to change the build tool used for a particular target, you can change the toolchain, and this seems to be supported via the [`scala_toolchain`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala/blob/master/README.md#scala_toolchain)

And I believe you can use a config to select the toolchain.

I'm unfamiliar with what `scala_repositories` does. I hope it defines the toolchain with a proper versioned name, so that you can reference the wanted toolchain correctly. And I hope you can invoke it twice in the same workspace, otherwise I think there is no solution.

Comment: According to https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala/issues/393 it is not possible to configure more than one Scala version in the WORKSPACE :(

Comment: In our project, we've set up e.g, "project_cc_library", macros, that generate e.g, "cc_library" rules. We want to control which flags are enabled depending on compiler attributes, like whether it is clang or gcc. One way we could do this is to use "copts = select(...)"; however, I cannot figure out a way to make the flags globally available, or indeed, available within the 'bzl' file where we define the macros.

Is there a way?